# Application of transformation $U_d$ that maps any qudit state to $|d-1\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, matrix-representation, quantum-state

When giving examples of universal gate sets in the paper [Qudits and High-Dimensional Quantum Computing](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2020.589504/full), the authors first define the transformation that maps any given qudit state to $|d-1\rangle$:
$$
U_d(\alpha): \sum_{l=0}^{d-1}\alpha_l|l\rangle \rightarrow |d-1\rangle, \ \alpha = (\alpha_0, \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{d-1})
$$
This can be decomposed into $d-1$ unitary transformations
$$
U_d = X_d^{(d-1)}(a_{d-1},b_{d-1}),\dots,X_d^{(1)}(a_1,b_1), \ a_l = \alpha_l,\ b_l = \sqrt{\sum_{l=0}^{l-1}\alpha_i^2}
$$
with
$$
X_d^{(l)}(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{I}_{l-1} &  &  &  \\
 & \frac{x}{\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2}}
 & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2}}
 &  \\
 &  \frac{y^*}{\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2}} &  \frac{x^*}{\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2}} &  \\
 &  &  & \mathbb{I}_{d-l-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So in the qutrit case, the unitary transformations are
$$
U_3 = X_3^{(2)}(a_2,b_2),X_3^{(1)}(a_1,b_1)
$$

where each is transformation is a $3\times3$ matrix.

Considering the example of mapping the state $|0\rangle \rightarrow |2\rangle$, we have $\alpha_0 = 1, \ \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0 = a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = b_2 = 1$. Hence we see
$$
X_3^{(2)}(0,1)X_3^{(1)}(0,1)|0\rangle = |2\rangle
$$
However, when mapping $|1\rangle \rightarrow |2\rangle$ we see
$$
X_3^{(1)}(1,1)X_3^{(2)}(0,1)|1\rangle = |2\rangle \\
$$

As it is not intuitively clear (to me), why is it necessary to switch the order of the gates (or where am I going wrong)? More importantly, given $U_d$, is there any method to determine the appropriate sequence for applying the gates $X_d^{(d-1)}(a_{d-1},b_{d-1}),\dots,X_d^{(1)}(a_1,b_1)$?

Comment: Well, in the first case, you swap |0> and |1> and then |1> and |2>. In the second case you first swap |1> and |2>. The second operation is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks @EvgeniyZh, however I had already noticed this and, unless I am missing something, this doesn't really answer how to determine the gate sequence when given $U_d$.

Comment: If you are guaranteed that $U_d$ is created via this construction, then you can invert it and look at what $|d-1 \rangle$ maps to; then repeat the construction.